# Is there a way to say 'lack of appetite' in one word?

Tags: word-request

Is there a way to say '**lack of appetite**' in one word? (for instance: '[disappetite](https://www.google.com/search?q=disappetite&oq=disappetite&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)' which I found a very few results of it and I'm not sure how much is acceptable).

Context:

> The patient had *disappetite*(?).

Comment: Can you give more context, such as the cause of the lack of appetite? Otherwise I can only suggest a slightly shorter phrase: “not hungry”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The medical term for reduced appetite is **[anorexia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anorexia_(symptom))**. This is the normal medical term for reduced desire to eat for a variety of causes, e.g. illness such as common cold, hormone imbalance, influenza, fever, and others.  However, this generic term for appetite loss should not be confused with **[anorexia nervosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anorexia_nervosa)**, which is a mental health disorder.

Comment: As far as I know, Anorexia nervosa is characterized by low weight and usually chronic. I'm asking not about the disease but about the symptoms (usually temporary due to diseases). Note that lack of appetite isn't necessarily to be anorexia nervosa which is a disease by itself. Lack of appetite is exactly the meaning that I'm looking for but just in one word.

Comment: @JudiciousAllure I think what Michael is trying to say is that what you are looking for is just plain "anorexia"

Comment: Michael, hope you don't mind the edit

Comment: Except when we consider the OP's context example.  If you say, *The patient had **anorexia**,* you will be misunderstood in almost every situation.  It will be understood that the patient had an eating disorder, not that the patient had no appetite.  Unless maybe you're conversing with doctors and nurses.

Comment: @EllieK - "Unless maybe you're conversing with doctors and nurses." - That is the point, given that the OP asked for a one-word equivalent of "The patient had _disappetite_". Sounds like a medical context to me, but they have not been back to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The technical term for loss of appetite is *anorexia* however if you use this in general conversation people might assume you were referring to a specific condition *anorexia nervosa* which in fact does not always involve loss of appetite.

Answer (score 1):

I would say I was **full**.  **Full**, however, means lack of appetite due to a particular reason.  That reason being that you have already eaten.

> Do you have an appetite?

> No I'm full.

*Full* works in many cases but if you had no appetite because you were sick, you would not say you were full.

Comment: I added a context. Kindly take a look at it.

Answer (score -2):

Inappetent. For example: "It is early attended with high fever and marked general weakness and inappetence".

Comment: 1. Adjective, OP asked for noun 2. Inappetence is usually reserved for animals, such as cats, dogs, cattle, goats, and sheep.